# How to make css grid - grid-template-columns: auto-fit work in IE

Tags: css, css-grid

Hello I am creating a project that explores many of the things css grids can do as well as flex.

I am having trouble finding a solution to get 
`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));` 
to work in IE (any)

Here is a codepen of the syntax I am working with:
https://codepen.io/jordanklaers/pen/rNaMMEV

I also have the project available that you can download to see what Im doing as well if youd like (but the codepen shows the exact syntax that doesnt work in ie but does in chrome)
https://github.com/JordanKlaers/flexCSSGrid

Comment: CSS grid support from IE Edge 16: https://caniuse.com/#search=grid-template-columns

Comment: I know there isn't usually a simple "add a prefix" for alot of the grid syntax, I was hoping there might be a different property or so to achieve similar results

Comment: I could not find a workaround. IE does not support the auto-placement : / https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-debunking-common-ie-grid-misconceptions/